# Error: az cli script failed. UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: az cli script failed. Github Ci pipeline that I seteup keeps failing

Tags: azure, github-actions

```
env:
  AZURE_WEBAPP_PACKAGE_PATH: '.'     
  DOTNET_VERSION: '6.0.x'           

on:
 
  push:
    branches: master

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET Core
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: ${{ env.DOTNET_VERSION }}

      - name: Set up dependency caching for faster builds
        uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: ~/.nuget/packages
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-${{ hashFiles('**/packages.lock.json') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-nuget-

      - name: Build with dotnet
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release

      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test --no-restore --verbosity normal

      - name: dotnet publish
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment job
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: .net-app
          path: ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp

      - name: Login to Aure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
            creds: ${{ secrets.AZURE_CREDENTIALS }}
            
  deploy:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        needs: build
        environment:
          name: 'development'
          url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}

        steps:
          - name: Download artifact from build job
            uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
            with:
              name: .net-app
            
          - name: Deploy to Azure
            uses: azure/CLI@v1
            with:
              azcliversion: latest
              inlineScript: |
                az deployment group create \
                -- name \
                -- resource-group  \
                -- template-file Template/template.json \
                -- parameters storageAccountType=Standard_LRS
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this a few weeks ago, something to with using "latest" was the issue.

Could you try replacing it with the below and see if the issue goes away?

```
- name: Deploy to Azure
        uses: azure/CLI@v1
        with:
          azcliversion: 2.37.0
```

Comment: I just tried it, it still fails with azcliversion: 2.37.0

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your issue is, but you are not logged in to Azure during the `deploy` phase of your work.

You are logging in to Azure and then starting a new job. This is a new fresh container and it has no previous knowledge relating to your account.

I would move the Login part to the `deploy` step and see if that solves your issue.

Apart from that, if the config you posted is the entire workflow you will run into an issue wit this part:

`url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}` since the step `deploy-to-webapp` is not in the config and as such there is no output to pull from.